# TypeError in_io.BytesIO with Python3

Tags: python, stringio

I'm trying to read a file in io but it returns an error.
It's giving me a `TypeError` which I'm not able to solve. This is the code I'm using:

```
str_summary = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM '" + str(overall_summary) + "'", conn)
s = io.StringIO()
csv.writer(s).writerows(str_summary)
s.seek(0)
buf = io.BytesIO()
buf.write(s.getvalue().encode())
buf.seek(0)
buf.name = f'data1.csv'
with open(buf) as red:
    csvdata=csv.reader(red,delimiter=",")
    tdata=[]
    for row in csvdata:
        rowdata = []
        BLANK=row[0]
        A1 =row[1]
        A2=row[2]
        B3=row[3]
        B4=row[4]
        B5=row[5]
        C6=row[6]
        C7=row[7]
        C8=row[8]
```

It  returns this error

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO
```

Comment: @Jan. To me it is not that's why I brought it here. Please help answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just don't use `open`, but use `csvdata=csv.reader(buf, delimiter=",")`

Comment: Gives me this eror,,, @Ruslan...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\PyQt5\Backup\Result Management System(RMS)\REMARE 2.py", line 2098, in get_results
    for row in csvdata:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: If you need a file object, then you can use `buf = io.FileIO(f'data1.csv','r+')`